# Where helm stores its data on a cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Alice deployes a chart from her computer to a k8s cluster.
Bob runs helm ls -a on that cluster and sees Alice's chart.

I am looking for any configmaps on my cluster that could hold chart info but cant find any.

Where is it then?

Comment: Helm (3) normally uses Secrets; also see [Storage backends](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#storage-backends) in the Helm documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you apply the helm release it convert the Helm template to K8s resources like **deployment**, **configmap**, **secret**, **statefulset** and those values get applied and stored to **etcd** datastore of **K8s**.

Still **helm** also create the **secret** for **release** so if you check the `kubectl -n <namespace> get secret` there will be **secrets**.

Secret name will be something like : `sh.helm.release.v1.<release-name>.<revision>`

Comment: Additional info... Helm encodes a lot of the information in the data block as base64 (twice!) and then ZIP'd... See https://gist.github.com/DzeryCZ/c4adf39d4a1a99ae6e594a183628eaee